# Edit of an answer treated as if it was an edit of the question ("intended to address the author of the post" etc.)

Tags: discussion

I suggested what I thought was a helpful edit to an already good answer (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9359517). But it was rejected with "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer". To me, that sounds like a reject reason that might be applied to an edit of a question, but not to an edit of an answer. In particular, it makes no sense to me in the context of this edit.

Looking at the review screen, I'm not sure I'd recognize that it was indeed an edit to an answer. (There are a couple elements on the screen that imply it, but I don't see anything overt.)

So can someone tell me what I did wrong here? How should I have proceeded? Or did the reviewers just confuse an answer for a question?

Comment: Without addressing whether or not the rejection was correct, I have to point out that the rejection reason *does* generally apply to edits of answers *as well as* edits of questions. When applied to an edit on an answer the "author of the post" is the author of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the point made by @Louis, the reject reason can be applied to an answer. In that case, it's referring to the author of the answer.

After looking around at other similar questions, I get the sense that my mistake was in adding my own content to the answer. If the author had mentioned the JavaDoc and I just added a link thereto, that would have been fine. But I went ahead and amplified on the reason for checking null in the first place, which materially changed the answer. I thought it was a change for the better, but still, it was a change.

So I should have done what the reject reason said in the first place: either comment or write my own answer.