# Boldly addressing the author! (By adding missing import-statements)

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

While doing some work recently, I wound up writing a code-snippet similar to the one I found in a relevant answer. When I tried to run it, I discovered there was a missing `import` (at least in Python 2.7.x *). When I made the suggestion that the extra import-statement be added, it resulted in this [rejected edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12356138), despite previous [nearly-identical edits](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13591421/2) being approved *on the same post*.

This leads me to believe that **either** the rejection of my edit-suggestion was incorrect, or the **previous** edit-approval was incorrect. Which one is it?

* The question's tags do not specify a version.

---

**EDIT:** This got flagged as a duplicate of another meta-question that talks about code-edits. However, despite some similarities (such as a horizontal rule being common to both), there are key differences; I'm asking about *making code runnable* by ***fixing minor omissions***, and *not* about adding brand-new blocks of code or performing major revisions to others' code style or content.

---

I understand that *extensive* revisions to an answer (especially if it's to the original code) are generally a [no-no](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304020/3159183), and are better posted as separate answers so that various styles and approaches can be more-easily compared and contrasted by visitors. I also grok that there is a [high bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319314/3159183) for code edits.

Regardless of these points, I'd been lead to believe that [proper import-statements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312054/5739296) are a [good thing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312054/5739296). Aren't they? Based off at least [one answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285477/3159183) by Deduplicator, I get the sense that code-edits are okay when they improve formatting, or make a question (or answer) more M, C, V, or [E](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Has this outlook changed recently?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if that edit should have been rejected. That said, your edit summary is not descriptive enough: you say you added an import statement, but, clearly, [the reviewers know it already](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u8otk.png). The edit summary should be like a commit message or a code comment: describe *why* you did that.

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks. I'll try to keep that in mind when suggesting code-edits in the future.

Comment: Don't be misled by the title, the question is the same as yours.

Comment: Also read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066